# Caching a function containing some constants, in Django

Tags: python, django, performance, caching

In a Django website I maintain (v 1.7), I divide every 24-hr day into various time-windows, and then depending on which time window a user logged in at, I process some stuff for the said user. It doesn't matter what date it is, only the time-window matters.

Currently, the time-windows and their related processing is done in a function in my **views.py** like so:

```
from datetime import time as time_object

def WhichWindow(time_now):
    window1_least = time_object(hour=0, minute=0)
    window1_most = time_object(hour=3, minute=0) 
    window2_least = time_object(hour=3, minute=0)
    window2_most = time_object(hour=6, minute=30)
    window3_least = time_object(hour=6, minute=30) 
    window3_most = time_object(hour=11, minute=50)
    window4_least = time_object(hour=11, minute=50)
    window4_most = time_object(hour=14, minute=55)
    window5_least = time_object(hour=14, minute=55)
    window5_most = time_object(hour=16, minute=55)
    window6_least = time_object(hour=16, minute=55)
    window6_most = time_object(hour=20, minute=0)
    window7_least = time_object(hour=20, minute=0)
    window7_most = time_object(hour=0, minute=0)
    if window1_least <= time_now < window1_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window2_least <= time_now < window2_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window3_least <= time_now < window3_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window4_least <= time_now < window4_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window5_least <= time_now < window5_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window6_least <= time_now < window6_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window7_least <= time_now < window7_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    else:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    return variable1, variable2, variable3
```

*Note: `time_now` in the function is essentially `datetime.now().time()`.*

The function above is accessed very frequently for every user. I feel if I `cache` my time-window definitions, it's going to be a performance boost.

What should I do? Should I simply add the `@cache_page(60 * 60 * 24)` decorator on top of this function? I feel if I do that, that'll cache the result of this function as well, whereas I solely want to cache the time-window definitions. So what should I do?

Please advise the best performing way to accomplish this, alongwith an illustrative example. I'm a newbie and still wrapping my head around most of these concepts.

Comment: "that'll cache the result of this function as well" well... yes, that is what a cache does. How do you want to cache the function if you don't want to cache the result?

Comment: @syntonym: I want to solely cache the time-window definitions. They're static and won't change.

Comment: Then you can move them out of the function in the module (or a different module or a class if you prefer).

Comment: Functions do something, where as you have some static data. You should put it somewhere static instead of creating a function and caching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to improve performance you should consider reorganizing the windows, since they are checked from midnight, (which probably is not the time when you have the most of the traffic).

Just to give a second approach, you could do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

windows = {}

window1_least = time(hour=0, minute=0)
window1_most = time(hour=3, minute=0)
window2_least = time(hour=3, minute=0)
window2_most = time(hour=6, minute=30)
window3_least = time(hour=6, minute=30)
window3_most = time(hour=11, minute=50)
window4_least = time(hour=11, minute=50)
window4_most = time(hour=14, minute=55)
window5_least = time(hour=14, minute=55)
window5_most = time(hour=16, minute=55)
window6_least = time(hour=16, minute=55)
window6_most = time(hour=20, minute=0)
window7_least = time(hour=20, minute=0)
window7_most = time(hour=0, minute=0)


def which_window(minutes):
    hour = minutes // 60
    minute = minutes % 60
    curent_time = time(hour=hour, minute=minute)
    if window1_least <= curent_time < window1_most:
        return 1
    elif window2_least <= curent_time < window2_most:
        return 2
    elif window3_least <= curent_time < window3_most:
        return 3
    elif window4_least <= curent_time < window4_most:
        return 4
    elif window5_least <= curent_time < window5_most:
        return 5
    elif window6_least <= curent_time < window6_most:
        return 6
    elif window7_least <= curent_time < window7_most:
        return 7


windows = {minute: which_window(minute) for minute in range(1440)}

def get_current_window():
    current_minute = datetime.now().hour * 60 + datetime.now().minute
    return windows[current_minute]

# Just for testing
print get_current_window()
```

In this way, you are creating a long dict to save each minute in the day, but it will happen once (when the server is started) and then you performance will be much better, O(1), since you are using a dict.

Once you have this, you can create a 1k windows if you want, the check will keep being "instant"

Answer (score 0):

If the declarations are static you can put them out of the function. Thus they don't get executed each time the function runs:

```
from datetime import time as time_object


window1_least = time_object(hour=0, minute=0)
window1_most = time_object(hour=3, minute=0) 
window2_least = time_object(hour=3, minute=0)
window2_most = time_object(hour=6, minute=30)
window3_least = time_object(hour=6, minute=30) 
window3_most = time_object(hour=11, minute=50)
window4_least = time_object(hour=11, minute=50)
window4_most = time_object(hour=14, minute=55)
window5_least = time_object(hour=14, minute=55)
window5_most = time_object(hour=16, minute=55)
window6_least = time_object(hour=16, minute=55)
window6_most = time_object(hour=20, minute=0)
window7_least = time_object(hour=20, minute=0)
window7_most = time_object(hour=0, minute=0)


def WhichWindow(time_now):

    if window1_least <= time_now < window1_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window2_least <= time_now < window2_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window3_least <= time_now < window3_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window4_least <= time_now < window4_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window5_least <= time_now < window5_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window6_least <= time_now < window6_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    elif window7_least <= time_now < window7_most:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    else:
        variable1 = #something
        variable2 = #something
        variable3 = #something
    return variable1, variable2, variable3
```

Of course you could also put them in a module, class, list, ...

Via PEP8 module level constants should be uppercase.

Comment: I see, you meant define them as global variables. So when I use these global definitions inside a class or a function, should I first declare `global window1_least`, `global_window1_most` and so on?

Comment: you don't need to re-declare them, just use them

Comment: You only need the `global` keyword if you want to write to them (because otherwise the written value will be in the current scope instead of the global scope). Because you only read them you don't need global.